# Does expansion happen on redirection part of a simple command?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, bash-expansion

From Bash manual

> **3.7.1 Simple Command Expansion**
>
> When a simple command is executed, the shell performs the following
>   expansions, assignments, and redirections, from left to right.
>
> 1. The words that the parser has marked as variable assignments (those preceding the command name) and redirections are saved for later
>      processing.
> 2. The words that are not variable assignments or redirections are expanded (see Section 3.5 [Shell Expansions], page 21). If any words
>      remain after expansion, the first word is taken to be the name of the
>      command and the remaining words are the arguments.
> 3. Redirections are performed as described above (see Section 3.6 [Redirections], page 31).
> 4. The text after the ‘=’ in each variable assignment undergoes tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal before being assigned to the variable.

It mentions expansions happen on the following parts of a simple command: command name, command arguments, and assignments.

I was wondering if expansion also happens on redirection part? If yes, can you give some examples? Thanks.

Comment: I guess you are mislead by (2) where it says *The words that are not variable assignments or redirections are expanded*. Note that contrary to how we commonly talk about this, it is not the *>c* in the command `a b >c` which is the redirection in the sense of the bash man page. We are talking here about tokenizing the line into **words**. The words here are *a*, *b*, *>* and *c*, and it is just the word **>** which is the redirection word.

Comment: I wonder why this post got downvotes. IMO, the question makes sense (I, personally, find this part of the man page a bit confusing too), and the OP showed his effort to research about the topic by quoting the relevant part of the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you redirect to/from the value of a variable or result of a command substitution, then that would have been expanded in step 2.

Example (creates the file called `file`):

```
outfile='file'
date >"$outfile"
```

You can not, however, do

```
redir='>'
date $redir file
```

as that would invoke `date` with the operands `>` and `file`.  This is because when the command line was parsed in step 1, there was no "word that the parser had marked as a redirection" on it.